# How to call api vs parameters cancellationToken xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, cancellationtokensource

I am building an operation that calls api with the cancellationToken parameter. cancel () from event A, when the party B is calling, the api will be caught, but I want this exception to be arrested on the api side. ..... help, it took me 4 days but it didn't work out

API server

```
public async Task<Actionresult> getText(CancellationToken token)
{
    string s= "";

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a += " number "+i;
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return badrequest("canceled")
    }
}
```

Client xamarin app

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

private async commandEventA()
{
    cts.Cancel();
}

private async commandEventB()
{
    var token =cts.Token();
    string txtkq ="";
    var client = new RestClient("urlwebb");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("");

    try
    {
        var a = await client.ExcuteTaskAsync(request,token);
    }
    catch(TaskCancellationException ex)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you share some code to explain that? It will be helpful to know what your wants clearly.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT 
I have added my code. hope you review and help

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What do you mean "*this exception to be arrested on the api side.*"?

Comment: @JuniorJiang Yes, I want to cancel that as an exception on the api side, not on the client side as currently

Comment: Then you can request a http cancle request in the `catch` method to api.

Comment: Yes, you can help me

Comment: But that will need server to deal with this request, client only need to send it.

Comment: That's what I want, now when I cancel at event A of the client it has caught the exception right at event B of the client. it never passes to the server

Comment: The code you've created here won't do that. You would somehow need to signal the API that the particular request in `commandEventB` should be cancelled. CancellationToken won't do that. It will only cancel the request client side.

Comment: I know my code is not correct, so I asked if anyone could fix it for me. Please...

Comment: @ThuậnVũ You could have a look at this example:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#examples

Comment: @Junior Jiang.  I've read it, and it doesn't refer to changing the cancellation argument of cancellationToken when calling api. I'm pretty sad because of that

Comment: @ThuậnVũ Hi, `cancellationToken` is a local property, you can set it be `public static`. Then it can be modified in other class.